# Two recyclerview one horizontal and one vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Two recyclerview one horizontal and one vertical. in same activity i want when i click on item of horizontal recyclerview item the vertical recyclerview update the json data

Comment: i am new to android plz help me

Comment: please be more descriptive

Comment: Flagging to close the question as off topic because it doesn't have much details

Comment: https://github.com/Wasich/Community1-master     this github link of my project plz plz guide me

Comment: actully i have two recyclerview in my activity.on top horizontal recycerview which contain category of the posts like news , sports, and in botttom the vertictal recyclerview wich contain post about the category . i wan when user click on news item the vertical recyclerview show the only news type data

Comment: Did you try to write any code or reading the docs.See how to create a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please provide proper code

Answer (score 0):

you need to call  notifyItemChanged() on your adapter that contains data you want to update